# Finding Fitted Forecast with ARIMA / Exponential Smoothing in R

Tags: r, forecasting, smoothing, ets, arima

I've written some code to sort claim dates, count them per month/year and I am attempting to forecast them with either ARIMA / exponential smoothing parameters.

See claims list:

```
            2012-01-31   82
            2012-02-29   65     
            2012-03-31   64
            2012-04-30   73
            2012-05-31   71
            2012-06-30   79
            2012-07-31   72
            2012-08-31   82
            2012-09-29   64
            2012-10-31   72
            2012-11-30   63
            2012-12-31   80
            2013-01-31   67             
            2013-02-27   65
            2013-03-31   84
            2013-04-30   68
            2013-05-31   68
            2013-06-29   66
            2013-07-30   64
            2013-08-31   69
            2013-09-29   66
            2013-10-31   65
            2013-11-30   56
            2013-12-31   76
            2014-01-31   75
            2014-02-28   58
            2014-03-29   80
            2014-04-30   76
            2014-05-31   80
            2014-06-28   68
            2014-07-31   82
            2014-08-30   79
            2014-09-27   60
            2014-10-31   85
            2014-11-30   60
            2014-12-31   76
            2015-01-31   75
            2015-02-28   84
            2015-03-31   77
            2015-04-30   79
            2015-05-30   91
            2015-06-30   82
            2015-07-31   98
            2015-08-31   65
            2015-09-30   77
            2015-10-31  115
            2015-11-30   79
            2015-12-31   80
            2016-01-30   91
            2016-02-29  105
            2016-03-31   77
            2016-04-30  107
            2016-05-31   85
            2016-06-30   89
            2016-07-30  112
            2016-08-31   88
            2016-09-30   90
            2016-10-30   79
            2016-11-30   85
            2016-12-31   66
```

The issue I'm facing with my code is that I am getting a mean forecast rather than my desired fitted data  similar to this example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115506/forecasting-a-seasonal-time-series-in-r

Please see the R code:

1. Sorting the claim dates and counting them

   ```
           library(forecast)
           library(ggplot2)
           library(xts)
           library(reshape2)
           library(zoo)
           library(lubridate)

           data = read.csv('Claims1.csv')
           data$DISABILITYDATE <- as.Date(data$DISABILITYDATE, "%m/%d/%Y")
           data

           str(data)
           as.Date(data[,1])
           xts(x=data[,-1], order.by = data[,1])

           data = read.csv('Claims1.csv')
           data$DISABILITYDATE <- as.Date  (data$DISABILITYDATE, "%m/%d/%Y")
           df <- xts(rep(1,length(data$DISABILITYDATE)),order.by=data$DISABILITYDATE)
           df1 <- apply.monthly(df,function(x) length(x))
           df1
           t(df1)

           str(df1)
           df2 <- data.frame(df1=c("Jan 2012","Feb 2012","Mar 2012","Apr 2012","May 2012","Jun 2012","Jul 2012","Aug 2012","Sep 2012","Oct 2012","Nov 2012","Dec 2012","Jan 2013","Feb 2013","Mar 2013","Apr 2013","May 2013","Jun 2013","Jul 2013","Aug 2013","Sep 2013","Oct 2013","Nov 2013","Dec 2013","Jan 2014","Feb 2014","Mar 2014","Apr 2014","May 2014","Jun 2014","Jul 2014","Aug 2014","Sep 2014","Oct 2014","Nov 2014","Dec 2014","Jan 2015","Feb 2015","Mar 2015","Apr 2015","May 2015","Jun 2015","Jul 2015","Aug 2015","Sep 2015","Oct 2015","Nov 2015","Dec 2015","Jan 2016","Feb 2016","Mar 2016","Apr 2016","May 2016","Jun 2016","Jul 2016","Aug 2016","Sep 2016","Oct 2016","Nov 2016","Dec 2016"),score=c(df1))
           df2
           t(df2)
           df2[-1]
   ```

   2.1 Forecasting with ETS (Exponential Smoothing)

   ```
           library(forecast)
           x.ts <- as.ts(df2[2])
           x.ts
           x.ets <- ets(x.ts)
           x.ets
           x.fore <- forecast(x.ets$fitted, h=12)
           x.fore

           x <- ts(df2[2], start = 2012, frequency = 12)
           plot(forecast(ets(x), 24))
           x

           plot(forecast(x, h=12))
           date1 <- ymd("2012-01-01","2013-01-01","2014-01-01","2015-01-01","2016-01-01","2017-01-01")
           abline(v=decimal_date(date1), col="blue")
   ```

[image: ETS Forecast]
 2.2 Forecasting with ARIMA

```
            ARIMAfit = auto.arima(x, approximation=FALSE,trace=FALSE)
            summary(ARIMAfit)
            plot(ARIMAfit)

            pred = predict(ARIMAfit, n.ahead = 48)
            round(as.numeric(pred$fitted,0))
            pred

            library(TSPred)             
            plotarimapred(pred$pred,x, xlim=c(2012, 2020), range.percent = 0.05)
```

My output is this:
[image: I have forecasted the claims but I need to get more #fitted results than the straight line method]

example of desired output
[image: Example of desired output]

Comment: What makes you think your data is seasonal? Just beacuse you have monthly data doesn't mean a seasonal model fits it best.